# Find my checked out files in other workspaces using TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I develop using VS2015 and TFS local workspaces on 2 machines. Right now I have no access to one of them and I'd like to be sure that I have no checked out files on the inaccessible machine.

Being myself the only user it would be enough to know whether there are files checked out by anyone.

Is there a way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I commonly have this use case both for myself and trying to find what files other users have checked out.  The free [Team Foundation Sidekicks tools](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) are great for this:

[image]

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: You can also use TF (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx) but Sidekicks are easier to use.